# Using python scrapy crawl Web pages by multithreading

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The possibility of using scrapy to crawl data by multithreaded, scrapy internal implementation is itself a multi-threaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scrapy` internal behavior is completely asynchronous and event-driven since it is based on [`twisted`](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

See [Architecture Overview](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html?highlight=asynchronous#data-flow), especially pay attention to the `Data Flow` section.

You may also want to take a look at [`scrapyd`](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest) project:

> Scrapyd is an application (typically run as a daemon) that listens to
>   requests for spiders to run and spawns a process for each one.
>
> Scrapyd also runs multiple processes in parallel, allocating them in a
>   fixed number of slots given by the max_proc and max_proc_per_cpu
>   options, starting as many processes as possible to handle the load.